# Report tcpdump progress?

Tags: tcpdump

I run tcpdump as follows:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -i eth0 -w dump.pcap host 1.2.3.4
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

Is there a way to see how many packets it has captured so far? Apparently BSD allows for a status signal, but I'm on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `-v` option of `tcpdump`. From [man tcpdump](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump):

> ```
>    -v     ...
>           When writing to a file with  the  -w  option,  report,   
>           every 10 seconds, the number of packets captured.
> ```

Sample output:

```
$ tcpdump -v -i eth0 -w dump.pcap
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
Got 227
```

Note that contrary to what the man page says, the "Got X" gets refreshed every second on the machines I could test this (using tcpdump 4.9.2).

Answer (score 0):

You can make `tcpdump` print the output on stdout and pipe it to `tee`. This way you can both save the output into the file and have it printed out on `stdout`. Once you have this, you can use `pv`/`grep`/`tail` or anything like that to track progress